# Ternary operation in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am using VB.Net with Visual Studio 2019

```
Public Shared intDbEnvironment As Integer = CInt(Command().Split(" ")(0))
```

Sometimes if no parameter is passed, the app crashes. Is there a ternary operator or something that I could use that sets the value to anything if its Nothing or "" or not a number

I've tried

```
Public Shared intDbEnvironment As Integer = Int32.Parse((Command().Split(" ")(0)))
```

TryParse Code

```
 Dim success As Boolean = Int32.TryParse((Command().Split(" ")(0)), intDbEnvironment)
```

Comment: Since there's a chance that you will have "not a number", you should be using the Int32.TryParse function instead.

Comment: I tried that too and it returned "False". I need a #. like 0 or anything

Comment: Show your TryParse code.

Comment: When TryParse returns False that means it can't be parsed into an int. You can use TryParse in an If statement and in the Else clause do whatever you want to do when you don't get an int.

Comment: try googling  >>VB.Net  Ternary<<.  But then testing for all 3 conditions (Nothing, "", not-a-number) is probably not what you want to try in a ternary statement.

Comment: Avoid Shared Variables!

Comment: That's not how you should be using TryParse.  One liners are great, but you probably need to avoid that for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @LarsTech What do you recommend?

Comment: Just follow the [Int32.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) example.

Comment: Be careful with functions like If() or iif. Both of them will evaluate all of the outcomes, before evaluating any of it (causing an error), which is frustrating.

Comment: @tgolisch Not so. Yes the IIf Function but not the IF() operator. The If() operator will only evealuate the second parameter if TRUE and only the third parameter if False.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim i As Integer
    Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, i)
    Debug.Print(i.ToString)
End Sub
```

If I enter a non integer in the text box - Guess what! I get 0. Because the Function will not attempt to add a value to i if it is not an integer. The default value of and Integer is 0 so that is the value from the declare.

Comment: That is a good solution but I need to get the CommandLine args before the event fires. The Public Shared variable doesn't permit me to assign it to a Function. This line of code is immediately declared after the Class statement